# tcl lsearch can't get something like this a\[1\]

Tags: tcl

I have a lsearch issue.

here is my code.

```
set aa 11
lappend aa a\[1\]
lsearch $aa a\[1\]
```

why doesn't it work?

Comment: Strictly, it works _as documented_, but gives you an answer you didn't expect.

Answer (score 5):

Try:

```
lsearch -exact $aa a\[1\]
```

By default lsearch uses glob-style matching.  The backslashes prevent [1] being treated as a command substitution, but then lsearch sees the item to find as a[1] which as a glob pattern just means "a" followed by "1".  So you need the -exact flag to have the item to find just treated as literal text.

Comment: Similarly, the pattern can be braced to have literal meaning as,  `lsearch  $aa {a\[1]}` which does the same.

Comment: Yes that works too, the { } preserve the \ so that lsearch sees it, thus turning off the glob-match interpretation of the following [

Comment: or `lsearch $aa a\\\[1]`

Comment: Welcome to quoting hell, only a few chosen have escaped.